# A non-jew killing Amalek

Tags: amalek

If a non-Jew kills an amaleiki is he chayev Misa or do we say that the amaleikeim are supposed to be wiped out ,and he would be patur ?

Comment: Seemingly the same argument could be made with Canaanites and  yet Adoni-Vezeq was punished https://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0701.htm